# Shuffling and training in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, shuffle, training-data

I am using this code to decode a CSV file:

```
def read_csv(batch_size, file_name, record_defaults):
   filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([file_name])
   reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
   key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
   decoded = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)

   return tf.train.batch(decoded, batch_size=batch_size, capacity=batch_size*50, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
```

Consider my CSV file as follow (40 rows; 10 times number 1,2,3 and 4):

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
```

Two questions:
(1) When I use **tf.train.batch**, with a batch_size of 10, and a number of steps = 4, the batches taken from the queue during the training session are:

```
step 1: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
step 2: [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
step 3: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
step 4: [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
```

... and I do not understand why. I thought it would sample the 1s, 2s, 3s, and 4s correctly in a batch of 10 for each step.

(2) When I use **tf.train.shuffle_batch** instead of **tf.train.batch**, the shuffling output something like:

```
step 1: [1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1]
step 2: [4,3,4,3,2,1,4,3,3,2]
step 3: [4,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,2]
step 4: [3,3,3,1,3,4,2,4,4,4]
```

Why some numbers are represented here, e.g. 13 times (number 1), or 8 times (number 4), instead of 10 times? For this reason, I guess that my epoch is not complete if I just use 4 steps for the training because some of the numbers are not taken.